# Object motion and action simulation Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, action

How to simulate motion of images and actions like here? http://kak-iskat.ru/?q=how+to+do+that

Comment: Questions describing your requirements and asking someone to write the code for you or explain how to write the code are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please identify a specific problem or question about programming. Include attempted solutions, an explanation of how the results differ from the desired results, and any error messages you receive. Please read the [About](http://www.stackoverflow.com/about) page and [this advice on asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery [animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$('.my_element').animate({"0px", left: "0px"}, 2000, function (s) {
    // Animation is finished
});
```

This will animate the element to the top left of the screen.

You can also get the position of the element you want to animate the element to by using [position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/)

```
p = $(".other_element").position();
$('.my_element').animate({top: p.top + "px", left: p.left + "px"}, 2000, function (s) {
    // Animation is finished
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define mathematically the positions of the elements in terms of time, and use `setInterval`, `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame` to update them step by step.

Or you could also try CSS3 animations.